# How to access a variable defined in another scope in less?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

To avoid style conflicts, I've put Bootstrap in a separate namespace as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13977230/471164):

```
.bootstrap-styles {
  @import 'bootstrap';
}
```

Now using a Bootstrap variable such as `@gray-lighter` gives an error:

```
.footer {
  // NameError: variable @gray-lighter is undefined in ...
  border-top: 1px solid @gray-lighter;
}
```

How can I access a variable defined in a different (non-parent) scope in less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that way you can't (see [#1848](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1848)).
If a namespace contains only variables you could do it like:

```
.footer {
    .bootstrap-styles(); // copy that namespace into this scope
    border-top: 1px solid @gray-lighter;
}
```

But since `.bootstrap-styles` also contains styles this will also put all its styles onto `.footer`. So if you really need to re-use BS variables in a namespaced manner you need to import them separately from styles, e.g. like this:

```
.bootstrap-styles {
    @import 'bootstrap';
}

.bootstrap {
    @import (multiple) 'variables';
}

.footer {
    .bootstrap(); // using Bootstrap variables here
    border-top: 1px solid @gray-lighter;
}
```

### ---

Also note that by wrapping the whole `bootstrap.less` into a namespace you actually break many of its styles (see [#2052](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2052#issuecomment-45681469) etc., so using it this way is quite questionable).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know any way to resolve CSS class conflicts between Bootstrap and other libraries without breaking Bootstrap styles?