# how to generate css (like .E.F) using less.js compiler

Tags: less

I would like to generate CSS using less compiler..

Originally I have a less file and I need to prepend every rule with some class (not a nested selector)

```
.E{  .F{  color:blue;  }  }
```

is going to generate

```
.E .F{color:blue;}
```

In my case I don't want it to be nested but should get generated in the following way

```
.E.F{color:blue;}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any ready to use Bootstrap css file with prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202817/is-there-any-ready-to-use-bootstrap-css-file-with-prefix)

Comment: possible duplicate of [LESS css nesting classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117133/less-css-nesting-classes)

Answer (score 1):

```
.E {
  &.F { color:blue; }
}
```