# Namespacing Bootstrap 3 classes with prefix

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, namespaces, prefix

I'm wondering what's the best way to namespacing bootstrap 3 CSS classes using a prefix.

This question isn't just about namespacing bootstrap so it applies only in a specific container (see here: [How to namespace Twitter Bootstrap so styles don't conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966259/how-to-namespace-twitter-bootstrap-so-styles-dont-conflict)), but to litterally change all generated CSS classes using a predefined prefix.

I started to add the prefix `pl-` in the LESS files almost everywhere, but I must be missing some things because I break some part of the styling. So I'm looking for a smarter solution...

For instance, the `.alert` class in `alerts.less` must become `.pl-alert`.

---

The point of doing this is that I'm writing a plugin which can be used by other people (included in their website) and I must avoid that they override my styles by mistake (they probably have a `.alert` class which would be merged with mine and making a mess), so I want to avoid that by using a specific prefix.

Comment: This approach is probably flawed in that Bootstrap applies some styles to generic selectors, such as `*`, `p`, etc.

Comment: Also, namespacing probably would prevent most overrides since a specific-class descendant selector has greater specificity. Only the most assertive of CSS statements (those containing `!important`, for example) would override.

Comment: @isherwood Yes, a specific-class descendant has a greater prority, but it would merge properties as well. I would override (I guess, if my script is loaded after or is more specific) if there are conflicts, but it would merge properties anyway, which is what I want to avoid, at least avoid it by mistake. Indeed Bootstrap applies styling to generic selectors, like `body`, `p` and so on, that's why I want to apply such prefix only to class names.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue and looking for some suggestions... I've found that the best way for me would be to have a namespace.less file in my bootstrap node project.

```
.namespace {
    @import (less) "../dist/css/bootstrap.css";
}
```

In my Gruntfile, I would create a task to compile another distribution. Something like this:

```
less: {
      compileCore: {
        options: {
          strictMath: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          outputSourceFiles: true,
          sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>.css.map',
          sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css.map'
        },
        src: 'less/bootstrap.less',
        dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css'
      },
      compileTheme: {
        options: {
          strictMath: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          outputSourceFiles: true,
          sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map',
          sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map'
        },
        src: 'less/theme.less',
        dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css'
      },
      **compileNamespace: {
        options: {
          strictMath: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          outputSourceFiles: true,
          sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>.css.map',
          sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css.map'
        },
        src: 'less/namespace.less',
        dest: 'dist/css/ml.<%= pkg.name %>.css'
      },** 
...
```

But there is some cleaning up I'd need to do afterwards. Specifically all the styles created by normalize.less and scaffolding.less.

I would create I grunt task using RegExp to replace the styles that start with `.namespace html` to be just `html` and the ones that start with `.namespace body` to be `body.namespace`

Then in my HTML markup, I'd just add the namespace class to the body tag.

Comment: What I did in the end was to load all Bootstrap Less files using @import inside the namespace indeed. But not the same way, I did it like this: `.ns- {@import 'bootstrap-file1.less' ...}` I believe I changed all imported files as well, adding a `&` , maybe not, i don't recall exactly, but the idea was not to have twice the same CSS class, all my bootstrap classes were prefixed with .ns-