# Bootstrap 4 invalid feedback with input group not displaying

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have been looking into Bootstrap 4 - beta, however when using `.is-invalid` with `.input-group` it doesn't seem to show up.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="label">Label</label>
  <div class="input-group">

    <div class="input-group-addon">
      label
    </div>
    <input type="text" value="" name="label" class="form-control is-invalid">
  </div>

  <div class="invalid-feedback is-invalid">
    <strong>Invalid Label</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

How are you meant to display an invalid message while using `.input-group`?

Adding the following CSS works as a workaround, but it seems odd.

```
.form-group.is-invalid {
    .invalid-feedback {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They haven't taken into account their own examples using input group addons and buttons, even with a column model. The markup does only facilitate "neighboring" elements, not parent > neighboring element (there is no CSS rule for that).

It seems, for now, you should fall back to Alpha 6 or program your own CSS classes accordingly. I've done the same, unfortunately.

Please note when reading my answer that this was posted just as the beta was released. :)

Comment: By April 2020 and v4.4.1 this issue is still not solved. The documentation states one thing and reality something different.

Comment: Its Spetember 2020, still havnt fixed.

Comment: Feb 2021 checking in

Comment: Nov 2021 checking in

Comment: Still an issue in February 2022 using Bootstrap v5.1.3

Comment: Looks like this issue to me: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23454

Comment: Still an issue in December 2023 using Bootstrap v5.3

Answer (score 66):

Boostrap 4 is very buggy. My suggestion is to replace:

```
 <div class="invalid-feedback">
 Text here
 </div>
```

With:

```
<div class="text-danger">
Text here
</div>
```

And the second one looks virtually the same and will not fail.

For a better look, try:

```
<div class="text-danger">
<small>Text here</small>
</div>
```

Comment: This does the job perfectly thanks ! As you said, it is very buggy..

Comment: Its sematically incorrect. But better than !important anyways.

Answer (score 22):

I solved it by adding `d-block` class:

```
@error('terms')
    <div class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
         <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
@enderror
```

Happy coding!

Bootstrap docs here about `d-block`:[Display property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Comment: I used this solution, and it seems quite practical.

Answer (score 16):

The way Bootstrap does override the `display` from `none` to `block` is by checking first for a previous `is-invalid` class, for example! Check this CSS out:

[image]

That means, in case of an error, first `is-invalid` must be applied on an element and then `invalid-feedback` on another afterward! Like the following in Laravel, for instance:

```
{{-- Either following an input --}}

<input type="password" id="registerPassword"
       class="form-control @error('register_password') is-invalid @enderror"
       name="register_password" required autocomplete="new-password"
>

@error('register_password')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
@enderror

{{-- Or separately in DOM --}}

@error('register_password')
    <div class="is-invalid">...</div>

    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
@enderror
```

Comment: If you want to force show the *-feedback, then follow this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50522718/2190689

Comment: Using Bootstrap 5.3 in Jan 2024 and this was driving me nuts.  Some things worked, others didn't - this answer solved my issue.  _thanks!_

Answer (score 10):

Working example with a trick using `flex-wrap` and `w-100`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="input-group flex-wrap">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span></span>
        <input name="name" class="form-control is-invalid" type="text">
        <div class="invalid-feedback w-100">Custom error</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! This is the easiest and most hassle free solution which just works with the existing Bootstrap classes. Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand what `flex-wrap` is doing in this example. Would `invalid-feedback` not just be displayed without it as there is a preceding element with class `is-invalid`?

Answer (score 10):

Add `.is-invalid` to the `.input-group`.

If the `invalid-feedback` element is preceded by an element with `.is-invalid` it will be displayed -- that is how server-side validation is supported.

Answer (score 4):

I found [this solution](https://www.codeply.com/go/DMDBmq8TJg/bootstrap-4-input-group-with-validation)

```
<div class="input-group ">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">Start Date</div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" placeholder="Date Input">
    <div class="invalid-feedback order-last ">
        Error Message
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspecting the `.invalid-feedback` class I've found this definition (bootstrap 4.3)

```
.invalid-feedback {
    /*display: none;*/
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: .25rem;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #dc3545;
}
```

You could copy and rename this class and use it without the built-in limitations

Answer (score 0):

here is my "diy" answer

html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row p-3">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label class="sr-only">End Date/Time</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend ">
                <div class="input-group-text error-feedback">Start Date</div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control error-feedback" placeholder="Date Input">
            <div class="invalid-feedback order-last ">
                Error Message
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append error-feedback">
                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.error-feedback{
    border:1px red solid;
}
```

[image]

I know there is a bit off but, IMO pretty good compared this [example](https://www.codeply.com/go/DMDBmq8TJg/bootstrap-4-input-group-with-validation)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-control-label">Name</label>
<div class="input-group flex-wrap">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span></span>
    <input name="name" class="form-control is-invalid" type="text">
    <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">Custom error</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is best practice if you can provide a brief explanation of your code along with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add the .is-valid/.is-invalid class to the parent element .input-group. Then you can change the css to add the red border to the child elements like this:

```css
.input-group.is-invalid .form-control,
        .input-group.is-invalid .custom-select {
            border-color: #FA5252;
        }

        .input-group.is-invalid .input-group-prepend .input-group-text {
            border: 1px solid #FA5252;
        }

        .input-group.is-valid .form-control,
        .input-group.is-valid .custom-select {
            border-color: #05A677;
        }

        .input-group.is-valid .input-group-prepend .input-group-text {
            border: 1px solid #05A677;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Bootstrap 4.3 and following code worked for me. Try adding "validated" class with "form-group" and group error message inside the input-group.

```
<div class="form-group validated">
    <label class="form-control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span></span>
        <input name="name" class="form-control is-invalid" type="text">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Custom error</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app, I'm namespacing Bootstrap's styles so that they don't pollute the styles outside my app:

```
.my-app {
  @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
}
```

What I found by looking through the generated styles is that the validation css ultimately gets clobbered due to the mixin that generates it into:

```
.was-validated .my-app:invalid ~ .invalid-feedback,
.was-validated .my-app:invalid ~ .invalid-tooltip, 
.my-app.is-invalid ~ .invalid-feedback, 
.my-app.is-invalid ~ .invalid-tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

Note that it's `.my-app.is-invalid` and **not** `.my-app .is-invalid`. It looks like this is a consequence of the `form-validation-state-selector` mixin that generates it, which has a comment suggesting it's the result of a [dart-sass compatibility fix](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1873#issuecomment-152293725). One hack I could do is add the `my-app` class to every input that needed validation but that's not ideal.

I was able to resolve it by extending my namespace selector with a wildcard as follows:

```
.my-app * {
  @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for django and django-crispy-form

I use

```css
.is-invalid .form-group{
    .invalid-feedback {
        display: block;
    }
}
```