# Force to show invalid-feedback in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Let's say I have HTML like this:

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="invalidCheck">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
            Agree to something
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        I am outside of `form-check`!
    </div>
</div>
...
```

I want to **force** to show the `<div class="invalid-feedback">...` without using JavaScript (want to use Bootstrap CSS only). And I know I can use CSS classes like `was-validated` or `is-invalid`, but `invalid-feedback` is outside of `form-check`. Is there an easy and simple way to show `invalid-feedback` by adding Bootstrap related CSS classes?

I found one solution:

```
<div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
    Now I am visible!
</div>
```

But I feel like it's a hacky solution.  Please advise!

Comment: In Bootstrap-4, can you validate a form without JS?

Comment: Using `d-block` display util would be the only Bootstrap way to force it to display. The feedback classes are designed to work with validation.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev can you please have a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081137/issue-in-jquery-validation-on-select-field)  of mine. It'll be very helpful to me I'm kinda stuck here

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use display classes to display it manually for example `d-block`

use it like so

```
<div class="valid-feedback d-block">
```

or

```
<div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
```

[Find more in documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/display-property/)

Comment: I dont understand this, if i set d-block on my invalid-feedback div, i will always see it even before the user tries to submit a bad form

Comment: @JsonStatham, yes, it is a strange question.

Answer (score 9):

There are better ways.

**1)** 
Look into a `was-validated` class, that you can set on the form like so

```
<form action="..." class="was-validated" method="POST" novalidate>
```

When set on the form it displays validation feedback and also colorcodes the input field.

Just add it conditionally on your form, when validation failed on the **server side**.

**2)** 
Or you can use some **JavaScript** to be in control of what is displayed. You can add this class dynamically

```
$('form').addClass('was-validated');
```

and you can also dynamically check if the form is valid like so

```
 if ($('form').checkValidity()) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a div with the `invalid-feedback` class, but which is not immediately after a required input tag, it may not show even after adding `was-validated` to the form. However, the following hack should work.

```
<form>
    <!-- form inputs to validate here -->
    <!-- something else -->
    <input type="hidden" value="hack" required> <!-- the hack -->
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Here is some global feedback to show</div>
    <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```