# issue in Bootstrap 4 validation on select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, validation, bootstrap-4

I'm new to jQuery and Bootstrap, I'm using jquery and Bootstrap 4 for validation of my form modal, whenever there is an error it must show the error below the corresponding fields, but in my case the select field gets overwritten by the error and select field disappears but it works fine for input field.

here have a look and if you want to have a close look on image just click on it..

[image: error]

As you can see the select fields get overwritten by the fieldError but it's fine for input field.

here's my jQuery validation code:

```
$(function(){
    setCategorySelect();

    $(document).on('shown.bs.modal','#manageItemsModal', function () {
        $('#manageItemsModal #btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
            if (validateForm()) {
                messageSuccess("Very well");
            } else {
                messageError("Oops!!");
            }
        });
    });
});

function validateForm() {
    var validationStatus = true;

    if ($('#manageItemsForm #selectedCategory').val().length == 0) {
        showFieldError(('#manageItemsForm #selectedCategory'), 'Must not be blank');
        if (validationStatus) { $('#manageItemsForm #selectedCategory').focus() };
        validationStatus = false;
    }

    if ($('#manageItemsForm #selectedBrandModel').val().length == 0) {
        showFieldError(('#manageItemsForm #selectedBrandModel'), 'Must not be blank');
        if (validationStatus) { $('#manageItemsForm #selectedBrandModel').focus() };
        validationStatus = false;       
    }

    if ($('#manageItemsForm #serialNo').val().length == 0) {
        showFieldError(('#manageItemsForm #serialNo'), 'Must not be blank');
        if (validationStatus) { $('#manageItemsForm #serialNo').focus() };
        validationStatus = false;       
    }

    if ($('#manageItemsForm #selectedVendor').val().length == 0) {
        showFieldError(('#manageItemsForm #selectedVendor'), 'Must not be blank');
        if (validationStatus) { $('#manageItemsForm #selectedVendor').focus() };
        validationStatus = false;       
    }

    if ($('#manageItemsForm #selectedBranch').val().length == 0) {
        showFieldError(('#manageItemsForm #selectedBranch'), 'Must not be blank');
        if (validationStatus) { $('#manageItemsForm #selectedBranch').focus() };
        validationStatus = false;       
    }   

    return validationStatus;    
}

function showFieldError(element, message) {
    $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    $(element).next().html(message);
    $(element).next().show();
}

function clearFieldError(element) {
    $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    $(element).removeAttr('required');
    $(element).next().html('');
}

function setCategorySelect() {
    var $categorySelect = $('#manageItemsForm #selectedCategory').selectize({
        selectOnTab: true,
        closeAfterSelect: true,
        persist: false,
        create: false,
        valueField: 'id',
        labelField: 'text',
        options: [],
        preload: true,
        onInitialize : function() {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/assetCategory/search',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    searchText: '*'
                },                  
                error: function() {
                    callback();
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    self.addOption(res.data);
                }
            });
        },
        load: function(query, callback) {
            if (query.length <= 2) return callback();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/assetCategory/search',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    searchText: query + "*"
                },
                error: function() {
                    callback();
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    callback(res.data);
                    $categorySelect.refreshItems();
                },
                fail : function() {
                    callback();
                }
            });   
        }
    });         
}
```

here's my HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form id="manageItemsForm">
         <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="selectedCategory" class="col-form-label"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Category</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="selectedCategory" id="selectedCategory"></select>    
                     <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="selectedBrandModel" class="col-form-label"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Brand & Model</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="selectedBrandModel" id="selectedBrandModel"></select>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                         </div>                         
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="serialNo" class="col-form-label"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Serial No.</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="serialNo" name="serialNo">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="description" class="col-form-label">Description</label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                        </div>                          
                    </div>
               </div> 
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-6">
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="selectedVendor" class="col-form-label"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Purchase Vendor</label>
                              <select class="form-control" name="selectedVendor" id="selectedVendor"></select>  
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>                                
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-3">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="selectedVendor" class="col-form-label"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Purchase Date</label>
                            <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy">
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="purchaseDate" name="purchaseDate" />
                                        <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon"><i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>                                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="supportTillDate" class="col-form-label"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Support till date</label>
                            <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy">
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="supportTillDate" name="supportTillDate" />
                                        <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon"><i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>                              
                    </div>
               </div>                                                       
           </div>
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-9">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="selectedBranch" class="col-form-label"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Branch</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="selectedBranch" id="selectedBranch"></select>    
                                <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                    </div>  
               </div>
               <div class="col-3">
                   <label for="purchasePrice" class="col-form-label">Purchase Price</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text input-group-addon" style="padding: 0.4rem 0.75rem 0.3rem 0.75rem;">&#8377;</span></div>
                            <input id="purchasePrice" name="purchasePrice" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount" style="text-align:right;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>  
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

By the way I am using jQuery in Spring boot and everything is working fine(save, update, delete) except for validation from jQuery.

Please help!!

Comment: where and how showFieldError() function is defined?

Comment: the `save` button on form is calling the `validateForm` @Sim1-81

Comment: can you provide working example ? it would be more clear to understand.

Comment: @java-user i asked for definition of the function showFieldError() , not for know where validateForm() it is triggered.

Comment: @Sim1-81 I've updated jquery please have a look

Comment: @Swati i've updated my question, have a look that might give you a view

Comment: @java-user stupid question: have you tried to use `return false;` instead of `validationStatus = false;`. Your code seems to be ok, the only doubt that i have is what `showFieldError(('#manageItemsForm #selectedCategory'), 'Must not be blank');` do. the same doubt is on `clearFieldError($('#manageItemsForm #serialNo'));`

Comment: @Sim1-81 can you please take a look on question, I've updated it.

Comment: @Sim1-81 have a look I've added `showFieldError(element, message)` and `clearFieldError(element, message)` functions

Comment: @java-user ok give me a bite of time, now i'm really busy and i can't post an answer, but i think that i found the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in Your HTML, the nodes of your .input-group does not have allways the same structure. In some cases you have .invalid-feedback just after the input such as this HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="serialNo" class="col-form-label"><span class="text-danger">* 
  </span>Serial No.</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="serialNo" name="serialNo">
  <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
</div>
```

For other fields the .invalid-feedback isn't after the input but outside from .form-group. take a look

```
<div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="purchaseDate" name="purchaseDate" />
   <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon">
       <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
   </span>
 </div>
 <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
```

This difference in HTML structure of the form made your showFieldError() and clearFieldError() not working allways as you expected, because `$(element).next()` don't catch the right DOM node for insert/remove the validation message. So in some cases clearFieldError remove the wrong HTML tag and this can make your selects disappear

```
function showFieldError(element, message) {
    $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    $(element).next().html(message);
    $(element).next().show();
}

function clearFieldError(element) {
    $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    $(element).removeAttr('required');
    $(element).next().html('');
}
```

So you have to fix Your HTML to obtain the same structure for all fields. Put the `<div class="invalid-feedback"></div>` allways just below the select or input field. Otherwise you have to change the selector that you pass to showFieldError() and clearFieldError() functions according to your HTML

Otherwise a simply approach is to add a ID to divs with class .invalid-feedback, an ID which you can easily manage by his related input ID, something like

```
<div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="purchaseDate" name="purchaseDate" />
       <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon">
           <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
       </span>
     </div>
     <div id="purchaseDate_err_mex" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
```

in this way you can pass the input name to your functions and them becomes

```
    function showFieldError(input_id, message) {
        $('#'+input_id).addClass('is-invalid');
        $('#'+ input_id +'_err_mex').html(message).show();
    }

    function clearFieldError(input_id) {
        $('#'+input_id).removeClass('is-invalid');
        //$('#'+input_id).removeAttr('required'); 
       /* don't need to remove required attribute from mandatory fields */
        $('#'+ input_name +'_err_mex').html('').hide();
    }
```

and the validation function

```
function validateForm() {
    var validationStatus = true;

    if ($('#selectedCategory').val().length == 0) {
        showFieldError('selectedCategory', 'Must not be blank');
        if (validationStatus) { $('#selectedCategory').focus() };
        validationStatus = false;
    }

 ........

    return validationStatus;    
}
```

You only check if the length of all fields is more than 0, so you can validate the entire form within a loop

```
function validateForm() {
        var validationStatus = true;
        var form_inputs = $('#manageItemsForm input, #manageItemsForm select')


        $.each(form_inputs,function(){

            var input_id = $(this).attr('name');
            clearFieldError(input_id);
            if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0 && $(this).is("[required]")) {
                showFieldError(input_id, 'Must not be blank');
                if (validationStatus) { $('#'+input_id).focus() };
                validationStatus = false;
            }
        });

        return validationStatus;    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't see working code because you using some external references like selectize.

I suggest you get used to "snippets" to provide code.

Bytheway, your problem seems to be just about styles. I can't know, but my bet is you just need to provide a css style for

```
.select::after.error {
color:red;
}
```

You can inspect and copy CSS code.

Comment: I appreciate your help but the problem here is the whole select field and it's options gets vanished