# Laravel does not seem to be validating data in the Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I have made this form and added it to the Blade:

```xml
<form role="form" action="{{ route('client.stepOne') }}" method="POST" class="login-box" autocomplete="off">
  @csrf
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group BHoma">
        <label>Country:</label>
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="" disabled></object>
          <option value="ir" selected>ایران</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group BHoma">
        <label>
          <span class="required-input">*</span>&nbsp; Type phone number
        </label>
        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="مانند: 9121234567">
        @error('phone')
          <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
          </span>
        @enderror
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
    <li>
      <button type="submit" class="default-btn next-step BJadidBold">ثبت و ادامه</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

And at the Controller, I tried this as Method:

```php
public function stepOne(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request);
    $validData = $request->validate([
        'phone' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    User::create($validData);
    
    return redirect(route('auth.login'));
}
```

As you can see I have specified `phone` input to be required. So if a user does not enter any phone number, an error message must be appeared at the page (and I have already defined `@error('phone')...@enderror`).

But now it does not show the error when user does not user enter any value as `phone`.

However if I uncomment `dd($request)`, I can properly get the results and this means that the method is properly connected as form action.

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

---

**UPDATE:**

`dd($validData)` returns this:

```
array:1 [▼
  "phone" => "2321312"
]
```

And if I didn't enter anything and leave it empty, nothings shown.

Comment: What does `dd($validData);` show?

Comment: @IGP I just added result of `dd($validData)` , plz check it out

Comment: but what does DD show if you submit the phone field empty? @firer

Comment: @MarwaneEzzaze `dd($validData)` shows nothing if I leave the input field empty! I mean the form just refreshes.

Comment: did you tried ***'phone' => ['required']*** instead of ***'phone' => 'required'***

Comment: @firer When you say *nothing is shown*, do you mean it shows an empty array or the code doesn't execute?

Comment: @Debuqer I just tried that but didn't solve this issue, no error appears when I leave the input form empty :(

Comment: @IGP No I mean the page just refreshes

Comment: @firer Then that shows the validation IS working.

Comment: @firer maybe you got the validation message. but there is something wrong with showing them.

Comment: @IGP When I leave the form input field empty, `dd($validData)` does not work and the page just refreshes. But when I enter a value it shows that like this: `"phone" => "12321"`. Where the issue is coming from? I'm really stuck with this...

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators . try this way so you can see error messages in controller. then you can troubleshooting them

Comment: @firer That is normal behavior. If you want the form to not submit, add html/js validation to it.  `<input name="phone" required>`. Laravel's validation only occurs after a form is submitted.

Comment: @Debuqer You're right dude, I just tied `@error('phone') @dd(0) @enderror` and it shows `0` meaning that the validation works fine.

Comment: is it possible to invalid-feedback has a css style for hiding the content? @firer

Comment: @Debuqer I don't know about all of that, but I just replaced it with standard bootstrap alert and it is showing that error. You can add your suggestion as answer so I can accept it

Comment: @firer i just posted my suggestion. also you can remove the invalid-feedback and check if your code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Bootstrap CSS rule that's generated for `.invalid-feeback` you'll see this:

```css
.invalid-feedback {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  color: #dc3545;
}

.was-validated :invalid ~ .invalid-feedback,
.was-validated :invalid ~ .invalid-tooltip,
.is-invalid ~ .invalid-feedback,
.is-invalid ~ .invalid-tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

In other words, the element will only be shown if its sibling element has the `.is-invalid` class, (or the parent has `.was-validated` and the sibling element is marked as invalid.) You should amend your Blade code to look like this:

```html
<div class="form-group BHoma">
    <label>
        <span class="required-input">*</span>&nbsp; Type phone number
    </label>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control @error('phone') is-invalid @enderror" name="phone" placeholder="مانند: 9121234567">
    @error('phone')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

So that the input element is given the appropriate class in case of error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing it like this:

```
$validData = $request->validate([
    'phone' => ['required', 'numeric', 'digits:10'],
]);
```

numeric to only accept digits, and have 10 digits entered for a valid phone number

Comment: How does this resolve the OPs problem of the `required` rule seeming not to work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673354/bootstrap-4-invalid-feedback-with-input-group-not-displaying) and the comments it seems invalid-feedback is not working well here

You can use this

```html
@error('phone')
<div class="text-danger">
{{ $message }}
</div>
@enderror
```

Comment: It's only not working well because OP is not using it properly. The question you linked to involves an HTML layout that makes it impossible for the two elements to be siblings.

Comment: You are right. I already know about sibling element and i think i have posted this answer in a non-css way, your answer is probably  better and more accurate than mine. thanks. @miken32