# Separate content script css from site css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-bootstrap

I'm building a browser extension and I want to use bootstrap in it. Problem is the bootstrap css is colliding with the page's css messing up some websites.

Is there a way to separate the content script css from the web page's css? Is there some known solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783217/how-to-really-isolate-stylesheets-in-the-google-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a **namespaced version of bootstrap**, where global styles are not applied outside a namespace CSS selector.

For generating this you must build bootstrap yourself using SASS.

This answer is a good resume of the procedure: [How to namespace Twitter Bootstrap so styles don't conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966259/how-to-namespace-twitter-bootstrap-so-styles-dont-conflict/21929419#21929419)

Comment: It doesn't prevent the upper layers from affecting my html code though

Comment: That'a a different topic. In this case you must an iframe or shadown-dom