# How can I use bootstrap 5 in the content script so that it does not conflict with the main CSS on the site? (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use the Bootstrap 5 library in the chrome extension. So I am adding the bootstrap 5 (CSS and js) files with a manifest to the content script but it conflicts with the main CSS file on some sites.

```
content_scripts": 
    [{
      "matches": ["*://*.amazon.com/*"],
      "js":["bootstrap.bundle.min.js","injection.js"],
      "css":["bootstrap.min.css"]
    }]
```

When I try to use bootstrap for example on amazon.com, some CSS elements conflict. I am trying to solve the problem with an artificial solution by commenting on some Bootstrap CSS codes.

I couldn't find any details about it. If there is a better solution or if the way I tried it is wrong, could someone tell me the logic of it or help me with another solution?

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caGeh.png)

[Css current solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRFJu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to avoid the CSS conflicts in the content script.
I think you can build a namespace bootstrap version.
Please check this. [Separate content script css from site css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359786/separate-content-script-css-from-site-css)